# How to close timepicker (pickatime) popup from js

Tags: javascript, materialize, pickadate

When I use the date picker, it can be closed by:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate().pickadate('picker').close();
```

But it doesn't work for the time picker, I tried to use another approach and it also didn't work. I use `timepicker` from the Materialize package.
Did anybody have the same problem and maybe solved it?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew3wkzv0/) with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found weird but working solution.

```
$(document.body).click();
```

This will close the time picker popup.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ampvo7q2/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (in case someone is looking in future)

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate('picker').close();
```